# Calling OnPaintBackground in OnPaint

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In our UI project we are using a set of custom controls. The custom controls were written some years back. All controls override the OnPaint mathod as given below. Is it correct to call OnPaintBackground in OnPaint Method?

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

Comment: do you have a requirement to paint something _before/after_ [although _after_ is a rare case] the client of your control paints something with its Paint event ?

Comment: no there are no such requirement

Comment: `Quote from MSDN:` _Inheriting classes should override this method_ `to handle the erase background request from windows`. _When overriding OnPaintBackground in a derived class it is not necessary to call the base class's OnPaintBackground._ If you are  simply calling like this in OnPaint, then probably you can get rid of it. Does not make any sense to me at least.

Comment: Will this result in flickering of the control?

Comment: If you are you doing any back color painting later in the code, then you may override OnPaintBackground & do that stuff here to avoid flicker. But `calling & delegating OnPaintBackground to the base from OnPaint does not make any sense.` _See this simple sample here to get an idea and understanding of OnPaintBackground - http://www.bobpowell.net/transcontrols.htm_

Comment: This *normally* will just end up painting the background twice.  Who knows, maybe they did something to tinker with the base implementation.  You are not going to find out unless you read the code or just try commenting it out.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from https://sites.google.com/site/craigandera/craigs-stuff/windows-forms/flicker-free-control-drawing 
EVERY time your control paints, there are 2 events fired. OnPaintBackground and then OnPaint. They always fire one after another. So as a user types, they will fire like this: OnPaintBackground, OnPaint, OnPaintBackground, OnPaint, etc.

This might help you understand the underlying thought process, but it still does justify calling OnPaintBackground method.